# Delete project and all setting from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

My question i hope is very simple for solution.

I try this:

1) I have wrong imported project X from folder (this project is inside a folder and the icon is the simple folder) with Android Studio.

2) I delete this project from Android Studio (for try to import the second time).

Now i try to reimport again:

3) When i go to search again project X now i see the icon Android Studio not a icon folder.

So my question is..Android Studio save some setting for this project? and how i can delete all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside the project you will find some Android Studio files.

- **.idea** : in this folder Android Studio saves the settings
- **.iml** in each module. In these files Android Studio stores the module information

You can delete these resources, and then reimport again the folder.

Comment: @AntonioBalduzzi Mark the answer if it resolves your issue. It can help other users.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to delete the whole AS project you can do so in the file explorer, just remove the project folder and restart AS. If the project appears on the recents just click it and it will go away.