# Android studio not reading the updated .gitignore file

Tags: git, android-studio

I am using the latest Android Studio. I have a project under Git (bitbucket), and the first time I clone the project, it is successful. Subsequently, when I try to pull the new changes, I get the "Git Pull Failed" error. Somehow some files in the .idea directory has changed. I updated the .gitignore file to ignore the files in that .idea directory, but when I try to pull again, the same error appeared. Any clues on what may go wrong? Thanks.

Comment: the .idea folder is just on vcs and pushed on the git repo. .gitignore file will be used for the new file.It means that you have to remove the .idea folder from git repo. Check the comments of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32942758/2016562

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: Android Studio has its own list of ignored files, as you can see under:

    Settings -> Version Control -> Ignored Files

But this list is a general list, not Git-specific! 

I struggled also with the problem that .gitignore not updated by Git inside Android Studio.

Did you try to use other tool like TortoiseGit to do the pull?